# Find median value of the largest clump of similar values in an array in the most computationally efficient manner

Tags: matlab, math

Sorry for the long title, but that about sums it up.

I am looking to find the median value of the largest clump of similar values in an array in the most computationally efficient manner.

for example:

H = [99,100,101,102,103,180,181,182,5,250,17]

I would be looking for the 101.

The array is not sorted, I just typed it in the above order for easier understanding.
The array is of a constant length and you can always assume there will be at least one clump of similar values.

What I have been doing so far is basically computing the standard deviation with one of the values removed and finding the value which corresponds to the largest reduction in STD and repeating that for the number of elements in the array, which is terribly inefficient.

```
for j = 1:7
    G = double(H);

    for i = 1:7   
        G(i) = NaN;
        T(i) = nanstd(G);
    end

    best = find(T==min(T));
    H(best) = NaN;

end

x = find(H==max(H));
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: I think that you need to formally define exactly what you mean by "similar values" for this question. Also, your code doesn't return 3 (for 101) for the example `H`, but 10 (for 250, which does correspond to the value that if removed would have the greatest reduction in standard deviation -is that what you want?). And constructs like `x = find(H==max(H));` are never necessary. You can use `[~,x] = max(H);` to find the index of the maximum (or minimum with `min`) value.

Comment: Finding the median is a special case of a more general problem known as Selection (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_algorithm), and can be solved in linear time and space.

Answer (score 1):

This possibility bins your data and looks for the bin with most elements. If your distribution consists of well separated clusters this should work reasonably well.

```
H = [99,100,101,102,103,180,181,182,5,250,17];

nbins = length(H);        % <-- set # of bins here
[v bins]=hist(H,nbins);
[vm im]=max(v);           % find max in histogram
bl = bins(2)-bins(1);     % bin size
bm = bins(im);            % position of bin with max #
ifb =find(abs(H-bm)<bl/2)   % elements within bin 
median(H(ifb))              % average over those elements in bin
```

Output:

```
ifb =     1     2     3     4     5
H(ifb) =    99   100   101   102   103
median =   101
```

The more challenging parameters to set are the number of bins and the size of the region to look around the most populated bin. In the example you provided neither of these is so critical, you could set the number of bins to `3` (instead of `length(H)`) and it still would work. Using `length(H)` as the number of bins is in fact a little extreme and probably not a good general choice. A better choice is somewhere between that number and the expected number of clusters.

It may help for certain distributions to change `bl` within the `find` expression to a value you judge better in advance.

I should also note that there are clustering methods (`kmeans`) that may work better, but perhaps less efficiently. For instance this is the output of `[H' kmeans(H',4) ]`:

```
    99     2
   100     2
   101     2
   102     2
   103     2
   180     3
   181     3
   182     3
     5     4
   250     3
    17     1
```

In this case I decided in advance to attempt grouping into 4 clusters.
Using `kmeans` you can get an answer as follows:

```
nbin = 4;
km = kmeans(H',nbin);
[mv iv]=max(histc(km,[1:nbin]));
H(km==km(iv))
median(H(km==km(iv)))
```

Notice however that `kmeans` does not necessarily return the same value every time it is run, so you might need to average over a few iterations.

I timed the two methods and found that `kmeans` takes ~10 X longer. However, it is more robust since the bin sizes adapt to your problem and do not need to be set beforehand (only the number of bins does).